# Unable to start computer after using sudo crontab -e

Tags: macos, startup, shutdown, sudo

I've set it so that my Mac will forcefully shutdown at 12:00 everyday. But I try to turn it back on, it shuts down again right after.

Answer (score 1):

What command did you put in the crontab file itself, `shutdown -h now` ?

Boot into single user mode (Command-S) to edit out the offending crontab entry and try the `pmset` method.

The command `sudo pmset repeat shutdown mtwrfsu 12:00:00` (noon) or `...00:00:00` (midnight) will accomplish what you are looking for without using `crontab`.

To cancel this, execute the command `sudo pmset repeat cancel`

Answer (score 0):

Boot to single user mode, mount the filesystem and then delete or edit the cron tab file for the affected user (or all users if needed).

```
/sbin/mount -uw /
cd /private/var/at/tabs
rm whatever
```

When you are done you can `exit` that shell to continue booting the Mac.